# Starred messages aren't showing their stars in the transcript if you use their permalink

Tags: bug, chat, firefox, permalink, chat-stars

In Firefox 29.02a, if a message is starred, and you visit it via its permalink, you won't see its stars in the transcript. This includes the messages in the starred message list on the right hand side of our chat rooms.

As an example, let's take this message from [RPG General Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)'s starred message list, which has two stars on it:

[image: Two stars: "The problem with D&D is... a great start for any number of sentences, really."]

If you click the timestamp, you can [visit the message directly in the transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13829089#13829089). It won't have any stars show up for it though:

[image: no star!]

But let's take the permalink for, say, the message [right above that one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13829023#13829023) and visit that URL instead. The stars show up!

[image: a star shows up!]

It's been like this for at least a few weeks.

Comment: Odd, because I can see the star in both examples. What browser do you use? I am using IE 11..

Comment: Firefox Aurora 29.02a. It seems this is specific to Firefox.

Comment: Oops, I think this may be [my fault](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217462).  Investigating...

Comment: OK, fixed in SOUP v1.6.1. Now, the interesting question is, how do we close this? ;-) Is it [meta-tag:status-completed], [meta-tag:status-norepro] or [meta-tag:status-bydesign]?

Comment: Whoops; confirmed - this was part of SOUP. I forgot I was using the SOUP script on one of my machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) user script caused by the inclusion of [this related CSS fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217462).  Specifically, there's another CSS rule that adjusts the star marker placement for highlighted messages which also needs to be overridden to restore proper marker placement.

I've just pushed a [hotfix](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/commit/141033d10fc895ae84becb725c83c42a4ff3a136) for this issue to GitHub as SOUP v1.6.1.  If your browser doesn't update the script automatically, you can [install the updated version here](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/raw/master/SOUP.user.js).

The fix is also included in the SOUP development branch version 1.7.5, and will be included in the upcoming SOUP v1.8.

Comment: Shouldn't this issue be migrated [here](http://stackapps.com/a/4488/22190) then?

Comment: Yes, it should, but I don't think the SE software is quite that flexible.  Anyway, I've asked a mod to somehow mark this as resolved.

Comment: No-repro fits best in my opinion, for those who don't use the script.